# Download attachments using Exchange Web Services Java API?

Tags: java, exchange-server, exchangewebservices, ewsjavaapi

I am writing a Java application to download emails using Exchange Web Services. I am using Microsoft's ewsjava API for doing this.

I am able to fetch email headers. But, I am not able to download email attachments using this API. Below is the code snippet.

```
FolderId folderId = new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, "mailbox@example.com");
findResults = service.findItems(folderId, view);
for(Item item : findResults.getItems()) {
   if (item.getHasAttachments()) {
      AttachmentCollection attachmentsCol = item.getAttachments();
      System.out.println(attachmentsCol.getCount()); // This is printing zero all the time. My message has one attachment.
      for (int i = 0; i < attachmentsCol.getCount(); i++) {
         FileAttachment attachment = (FileAttachment)attachmentsCol.getPropertyAtIndex(i);
         String name = attachment.getFileName();
         int size = attachment.getContent().length;
      }
   }
}
```

`item.getHasAttachments()` is returning `true`, but `attachmentsCol.getCount()` is `0`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to load property `Attachments` before you can use them in your code. You set it for `ItemView` object that you pass to FindItems method.

Or you can first find items and then call `service.LoadPropertiesForItems` and pass `findIesults` and `PropertySet` object with added `EmailMessageSchema.Attachments`

Comment: @grapkulec could you provide a simple sample for this? Would be very nice of you.

Answer (score 5):

```
FolderId folderId = new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, "mailbox@example.com"); 
findResults = service.findItems(folderId, view); 
service.loadPropertiesForItems(findResults, new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.FirstClassProperties, EmailMessageSchema.Attachments));

for(Item item : findResults.getItems()) { 
   if (item.getHasAttachments()) { 
      AttachmentCollection attachmentsCol = item.getAttachments(); 
      System.out.println(attachmentsCol.getCount());
      for (int i = 0; i < attachmentsCol.getCount(); i++) { 
         FileAttachment attachment = (FileAttachment)attachmentsCol.getPropertyAtIndex(i); 
         attachment.load(attachment.getName());
      } 
   } 
}
```

Comment: while your answer might work, it could use some comment on what your code is doing, or what you have changed from OP's code!

Comment: @Yury: If I've read well, you have literally added a single line. Consider trimming the code and just explaining what it does and why it is needed

Answer (score 1):

Honestly as painful as it is, I'd use the PROXY version instead of the Managed API. It's a pity, but the managed version for java seems riddled with bugs.

Comment: I can't seem to find any references for this?  Could you provide a link?

Comment: It's just what you get when you run wsimport or other such codegens against the raw WSDL. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd877302(v=exchg.150).aspx

Answer (score 0):

before checking for item.getHasAttachments(), you should do item.load(). Otherwise there is a chance your code will not load the attachment and attachmentsCol.getCount() will be 0.
Working code with Exchange Server 2010 :

```
ItemView view = new ItemView(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
view.getOrderBy().add(ItemSchema.DateTimeReceived, SortDirection.Descending);  
FindItemsResults < Item > results = service.findItems(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, new SearchFilter.IsEqualTo(EmailMessageSchema.IsRead, true), view);
Iterator<Item> itr = results.iterator();
while(itr.hasNext()) {
    Item item = itr.next();
    item.load();
    ItemId itemId = item.getId();
    EmailMessage email = EmailMessage.bind(service, itemId);
    if (item.getHasAttachments()) { 
        System.err.println(item.getAttachments());
        AttachmentCollection attachmentsCol = item.getAttachments(); 
        for (int i = 0; i < attachmentsCol.getCount(); i++) {
            FileAttachment attachment=(FileAttachment)attachmentsCol.getPropertyAtIndex(i);
            attachment.load("C:\\TEMP\\" +attachment.getName());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: when I call `load()` I get `microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.exception.service.remote.ServiceRequestException: The request failed. ParseError at [row,col]:[93,9101]
Message: Character reference "&#`

Comment: @Black - that's because the attachment may be an Item Attachment which has some special characters in the body or subject line. that is a know issue.
https://github.com/OfficeDev/ews-java-api/issues/440

Comment: Doesn't this issue make the EWS api totally non-viable?

Comment: I found the solution in a patch available here: https://github.com/RavnSystems/ews-java-api/commit/845f20fe1e33cbb1e7c5020df3de6291b56268dd

Answer (score 0):

Little late for the answer, but here is what I have.

```
HashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>> attachments = new HashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>>();    

if (emailMessage.getHasAttachments() || emailMessage.getAttachments().getItems().size() > 0) {

            //get all the attachments
            AttachmentCollection attachmentsCol = emailMessage.getAttachments();

            log.info("File Count: " +attachmentsCol.getCount());

            //loop over the attachments
            for (int i = 0; i < attachmentsCol.getCount(); i++) {
                Attachment attachment = attachmentsCol.getPropertyAtIndex(i);
                //log.debug("Starting to process attachment "+ attachment.getName());

                   //FileAttachment - Represents a file that is attached to an email item
                    if (attachment instanceof FileAttachment || attachment.getIsInline()) {

                        attachments.putAll(extractFileAttachments(attachment, properties));

                    } else if (attachment instanceof ItemAttachment) { //ItemAttachment - Represents an Exchange item that is attached to another Exchange item.

                        attachments.putAll(extractItemAttachments(service, attachment, properties, appendedBody));
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            log.debug("Email message does not have any attachments.");
        }


//Extract File Attachments
try {
        FileAttachment fileAttachment = (FileAttachment) attachment;
        // if we don't call this, the Content property may be null.
        fileAttachment.load();

        //extract the attachment content, it's not base64 encoded.
        attachmentContent = fileAttachment.getContent();

        if (attachmentContent != null && attachmentContent.length > 0) {

            //check the size
            int attachmentSize = attachmentContent.length;

            //check if the attachment is valid
            ValidateEmail.validateAttachment(fileAttachment, properties,
                    emailIdentifier, attachmentSize);

            fileAttachments.put(UtilConstants.ATTACHMENT_SIZE, String.valueOf(attachmentSize));

            //get attachment name
            String fileName = fileAttachment.getName();
            fileAttachments.put(UtilConstants.ATTACHMENT_NAME, fileName);

            String mimeType = fileAttachment.getContentType();
            fileAttachments.put(UtilConstants.ATTACHMENT_MIME_TYPE, mimeType);

            log.info("File Name: " + fileName + "  File Size: " + attachmentSize);


            if (attachmentContent != null && attachmentContent.length > 0) {
                //convert the content to base64 encoded string and add to the collection.
                String base64Encoded = UtilFunctions.encodeToBase64(attachmentContent);
                fileAttachments.put(UtilConstants.ATTACHMENT_CONTENT, base64Encoded);
            }



//Extract Item Attachment
try {
        ItemAttachment itemAttachment = (ItemAttachment) attachment;

        PropertySet propertySet = new PropertySet(
                BasePropertySet.FirstClassProperties, ItemSchema.Attachments, 
                ItemSchema.Body, ItemSchema.Id, ItemSchema.DateTimeReceived,
                EmailMessageSchema.DateTimeReceived, EmailMessageSchema.Body);

        itemAttachment.load();
        propertySet.setRequestedBodyType(BodyType.Text);

        Item item = itemAttachment.getItem();

        eBody = appendItemBody(item, appendedBody.get(UtilConstants.BODY_CONTENT));

        appendedBody.put(UtilConstants.BODY_CONTENT, eBody);

        /*
         * We need to check if Item attachment has further more
         * attachments like .msg attachment, which is an outlook email
         * as attachment. Yes, we can attach an email chain as
         * attachment and that email chain can have multiple
         * attachments.
         */
        AttachmentCollection childAttachments = item.getAttachments();
        //check if not empty collection. move on
        if (childAttachments != null && !childAttachments.getItems().isEmpty() && childAttachments.getCount() > 0) {

            for (Attachment childAttachment : childAttachments) {

                if (childAttachment instanceof FileAttachment) {

                    itemAttachments.putAll(extractFileAttachments(childAttachment, properties, emailIdentifier));

                } else if (childAttachment instanceof ItemAttachment) {

                    itemAttachments = extractItemAttachments(service, childAttachment, properties, appendedBody, emailIdentifier);
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new Exception("Exception while extracting Item Attachments: " + e.getMessage());
    }
```