# Retrieving Email attachment from Outlook

Tags: java, outlook

I have a requirement, I am getting more bounced emails when i send some email newsletters to my clients and I am sending the email fron Outlook. Bounced email is coming from "Mail Delivery Subsystem" and it has some attachments. In that attachments, it is having my original mail. I want to extract that original email through java. I would like to know any feasible solution for this

Any help in this regard is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

For **Exchange Server 2007+**, you could use Microsoft [Java EWS API](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/ewsjavaapi) or just talk [directly to EWS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exchange/dd877045%28v=exchg.140%29.aspx). See [related SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6585994/175679).

You would have to use .NET to integrate directly with Outlook via [VSTO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/hh133430.aspx).